# Showing $f(B_r)$ is relatively compact for a certain $f$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $g:B_r\to X$ a continuous function, where $B_r:=\{x\in X\mid \|x\|\leq r\}$.

Suppose that

- $g(x)\neq 0$, for all $x\in B_r$.
- $g(B_r)$ is relatively compact.

Define $f:B_r\to B_r$ by $f(x)=-r\frac{g(x)}{\|g(x)\|}$.

> I want to show that $f(B_r)$ is relatively compact.

I'm trying to apply the "sequential criterion". For this, we need to show that every sequence in $f(B_r)$ has a subsequence which converges in $X$.

Let $y_n=-r\frac{g(x_n)}{\|g(x_n)\|}$ be a sequence in $f(B_r)$. Since $g(B_r)$ is relatively compact, $z_n=g(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $z_{n'}=g(x_{n'})$. Let us write
$$\lim_{n'\to\infty} z_{n'}=\lim_{n'\to\infty} g(x_{n'})=z.$$

If $z\neq 0$, then $y_n$ has the convergent subsequence $y_{n'}=-r\frac{g(x_{n'})}{\|g(x_{n'})\|}$, which converges to $-r\frac{z}{\|z\|}$.

**Question:** How to deal with the case $z=0$?

Different arguments (without sequences) would also be appreciated.

---

### Edit

The assertion that $f(B_r)$ is relatively compact came from the image below (page 22 in [this link](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~prazak/vyuka/101/Literatura/vittorino-FP.pdf)). Theorem 1.18 is the [Schauder–Tychonoff fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem#History).

> [image]

Comment: Since $z$ is defined as a limit point of $g(x_{n'})$ and $g$ is a continuous, non-zero function, we can conclude that the case of $z = 0$ would never arise. And since that's the case, we should never have some $z \not= 0$ where $||z|| = 0$ since this is a norm on a Banach space.

Comment: I don't have a counterexample, but I suspect this is false in general. If you can make the range of $g$ into a Hilbert Cube, with the origin removed, then $g(B_r)$ will have an infinite-dimensional span, due to the width of the cube becoming increasingly narrow. But, forming $f$ will exaggerate these distances, creating a set that is not relatively compact.

Comment: @TheoBendit Could you please take a look at my edit? Maybe there is some missing hypothesis in my reasoning. What do you think?

Comment: It is not clear to me how one can rule out the possibility that $0 \in \overline{g(B_r)}$. If one can, then there is a straightforward proof that $f(B_r)$ is relatively compact.

Comment: @copper.hat Suppose we can. How would be your straightforward proof?

Comment: Then we can write $f = h \circ g$, where $h(x) = r {x \over \|x\|}$ and $h$ is continuous on $\overline{g(B_r)}$. Since the latter set is compact, so is $h(\overline{g(B_r)})$ and since $f(B_r) \subset h(\overline{g(B_r)})$ it follows that $\overline{f(B_r)}$ is compact.

Comment: @Pedro: I haven't added anything new, note that the sticking point in your proof is also the $z=0$ part.

Comment: I'm curious about this. Bump ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat I'm curious too. The way the proof is written suggests that the relative compactness should be easily deduced. However, it seems that this is not the case.

Comment: I agree, I am guessing that the proposition is true, but the proof is flawed. Perhaps if one could show that $f$ is uniformly continuous then the proof would work, but that is not clear to me.

Comment: I keep these sort of unanswered tabs open for a few weeks and then give up :-(. Am really curious if this is a proof bug...